# Cleaning hot ash out of a woodstove without creating soot plumes

Tags: cleaning, fireplace, woodstove

We got a woodstove insert last year and it worked great. The only problem was that every time I go to clean out the ashes, it creates small plumes of black soot that dusted all of our shelves and created a cleaning fiasco each and every day. My method of cleaning the ashes was:

1. In the morning (roughly 6 AM), open the door and use a metal pan to scoop the ashes into a metal bucket (this is what created the plumes)
2. Dump the (still hot) ashes into our firepit out back
3. About once a week transfer the firepit ashes into a compost bin

This year I'd like to cut down on the soot plumes as much as possible. I've been researching "ash vacuums" but they all stipulate that you can't suck up hot embers or hot ash with them. The problem is, we keep the fire going around the clock. As soon as we wake up, I'm cleaning out the old embers/ashes and starting a new fire to carry us through the day. So we're always going to be cleaning out hot embers/ash each and every morning.

Any creative solutions here? My wife seems to think that there are hot-ember-friendly ash vacs that are just a little bit more expensive, but I haven't found any. So in absence of those, what are some crafty ways to prevent soot plumes when cleaning our the hot ash of my woodstove?

Comment: you can put a 20x20 cheap air filter on a box fan and keep it next to the stove to use while cleaning to trap a good chunk of the plumes and keep them from drifting/collecting other places like a bookshelf.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep the ash bucket right in front of the open door of the stove, so that the draft of the warm stove will pull any soot plume into the stove, and the distance the ash is being moved is minimized.

Minimize disturbance when scooping ash. Slide the scoop all the way into the bucket so the ash is simply transferring from the scoop to the bucket, without falling through the air at all. This may require tipping the bucket sideways when it's near empty. *An actual ash shovel does this better than what comes to mind when you say "metal pan," but you don't show a picture.*

Cover the bucket with a tight fitting metal cover as soon as the scooping is done.